# How to properly stack nested navigators within an App Container?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo, react-navigation-stack

I currently have an `AppContainer` which consists of a bottom tab navigator and currently one more navigation set for Profile settings. I am trying to understand how to properly arrange everything, specifically how to nest navigation in one tab `Profile` so I can access two other pages `QrCode` and `EditAccount` each through two buttons. How do I achieve the below output? I believe I have to nest profile navigation somehow.

MY TABS BELOW

1. **Home**
2. **Queue**
3. **Profile**
   :in here i have two other pages i can access **QRCode** and **EditAccounts**

**App.js**

```
    const bottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
      {
        Home: {
          screen: Home,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
              <Icon name="home" size={25} color={tintColor} />
            )
          }
        },
        Queue: {
          screen: Queue,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
              <Icon name="comments" size={25} color={tintColor} />
            )
          }
        },
Profile: {
      screen: Profile,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon name="user" size={25} color={tintColor} />
        )
      }
    }
})

const navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  return { 
    headerTitle: 'hello',
    headerStyle: {
      height: '45%',
      backgroundColor: 'black'
    },
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerLeft: (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback 
          style={{ /* Put your style here */}}
          onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} >
          <Ionicons  name="ios-arrow-dropleft" size={32} color="white" />
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
  }
}

const ProfileNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  //Profile: { screen: Profile},
  QR: { screen: GenerateQR, navigationOptions },
  Profile: { screen: Profile },
  EditAccount: { screen: EditAccount, navigationOptions }
});

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  tabs: bottomTabNavigator,
  profile: ProfileNavigator
})

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

**After Applying Answer**

The solution offers works as needed with the code below:

```
  const navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
      return { 
        headerTitle: 'hello',
        headerStyle: {
          height: '45%',
          backgroundColor: 'black'
        },
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerLeft: (
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback 
              style={{ /* Put your style here */}}
              onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} >
              <Ionicons  name="ios-arrow-dropleft" size={32} color="white" />
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        )
      }
    }

    const ProfileNavigator = createStackNavigator({
      Profile: { screen: Profile},
      QR: { screen: GenerateQR, navigationOptions },
      EditAccount: { screen: EditAccount, navigationOptions }
    });

//ADDED
ProfileNavigator.navigationOptions = () => {
  const navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
    headerMode: 'none',
  };
  return navigationOptions;
};


    const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
      tabs: bottomTabNavigator,
      profile: ProfileNavigator
    })

    const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

The only issue is I am unsure how to port over the header options to the tabs in the in the `bottomTabNavigator`. I have a custom component in place for the profile page that makes it look like this (black bar with button icon for Profile):

[image]

I can then navigate to the EditAccounts by pressing on the user icon. But when I navigate back from EditAccounts back to profile, the page renders with the `navigationOptions` header like so:

[image]

How do I apply this properly so I can lean simply on the navigationOptions header and push a custom name onto it (get rid of my custom component in that case)?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 cases.

1. If you want to keep tabs when accessing `QR` or `EditAccount`

```
const BottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  ...
  Profile: {
   screen: ProfileNavigator,
  }
})

const ProfileNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Profile: { screen: Profile},
  QR: { screen: GenerateQR, navigationOptions },
  EditAccount: { screen: EditAccount, navigationOptions }
});

ProfileNavigator.navigationOptions = () => {
  const navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
    headerMode: 'none',
  };
  return navigationOptions;
};

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(BottomTabNavigator);
```

2. If you don't want to keep tabs

```
const BottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  ...
  Profile: {
   screen: Profile,
  }
})

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Tabs: BottomTabNavigator,
  QR: { screen: GenerateQR, navigationOptions },
  EditAccount: { screen: EditAccount, navigationOptions }
})

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

### UPDATED:

Add `navigationOptions` to `ProfileNavigator` to remove header

```
ProfileNavigator.navigationOptions = () => {
  const navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
    headerMode: 'none',
  };
  return navigationOptions;
};
```

Comment: I added an edit with a followup if you could offer some help. I applied your first solution with the tabs visible. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I updated my answer to remove header. Try to see if it works for you

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. How would I apply this within the code I have?

Comment: Just add right after `const ProfileNavigator = createStackNavigator({})`. Updated answer above

Comment: No dice, I added it (also to the question so you can see) but it still pushes down the black bar. I even removed the black bar to keep all the regular items but no luck. Will have to play with it